# React ref binding results in: TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am able to copy the example in the React docs to create a ref and then target it on Code Sandbox, but for some reason I can't replicate it in a local project. I'm using react 16.6.3 which is the latest version.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
SelectDonation.save_donation_amount
src/components/SelectDonation.js:19
  16 | save_donation_amount () {
  17 |   
  18 |   // testing refs
> 19 |   this.customDonationInput.current.focus();
     | ^  20 |   
  21 |   // prevent pageload
  22 |   // grab the custom amount
```

Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Button, Modal, Form, Input, Radio} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import store from "../reducer";

export default class SelectDonation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.customDonationInput = React.createRef();
    this.save_donation_amount = this.save_donation_amount.bind(this);
  }

  save_donation_amount () {
    this.customDonationInput.current.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Input
              type='number'
              placeholder='Custom Amount'
              name='donation_amount'
              id='custom_amount'
              ref={this.customDonationInput}
              // value={store.donation_amount}
              defaultValue={store.donation_amount}
            />

            <Button
              primary
              onClick={
                this.save_donation_amount
              }>Next Step
            </Button>
        </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

From the error it seems the .current property isn't there. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: do you get this in browser, in unit test or maybe SSR?

Comment: In browser, specifically Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused because Semantic UI React's `<Form.Input>` is a functional component and thus can not receive refs. Changing the element to a regular `<input>` fixed the issue

Comment: Yes I am also facing the same issue!